# Why the length of cipher text generated by php via mcrypt_encrypt() is different from the one generated by C via openssl encryption library

Tags: php, c, encryption, aes

I tried [this code](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message) from openssl wiki which generate a cipher text via aes-256 algorithm.
The length of input plain text is 512 bytes. The length of output, however, is difference. PHP generate an output which length is 512 bytes, whereas the C generate a 528 bytes long cipher text.

why there exist such a difference and how could I use an aes-256 algorithm to encrypt an text in PHP and then decrypt it in C?

Comment: Removed the last part of the question, asking for examples is explicitly off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up e.g. the comments section of [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) to pad the plaintext message using the PKCS#7 padding method. PHP uses zero padding up to the first value that is on the block boundary instead of the ad-hoc PKCS#7 padding method that is normally used.

The problem with zero padding is that it is not deterministic for messages that may end with a `00` byte value as this may be removed during unpadding.